# Zipstream in Laravel 5.4 - Data is corrupted

Tags: php, laravel, file, zipstream

I am using the method to generate an example zip file.

Unfortunately the output of the zip file does not decompress to the expected input.

```
public function generateZip(Request $req) { 
    $response = new StreamedResponse(function()
    {
        $opt = array(

            'comment' => 'test zip file.',
            'send_headers'=>true,
        );

        $zip = new ZipStream\ZipStream('example.zip');

        # create a file named 'hello.txt' 
        $zip->addFile('hello.txt', 'This is the contents of hello.txt');


        # finish the zip stream
        $zip->finish();
     });


    return $response;
```

The file generated `example.zip`, and upon unzipping the file unzipped "hello.txt" but it's contents are one blank new line then

```
…»,V¢íåTÖ‰¸ºí‘ºíbÖ¸4Öå‘úú|Ωíä
```

My effort has been based off of this code:

[Using ZipStream in Symfony: streamed zip download will not decompress using Archive Utility on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44697218/using-zipstream-in-symfony-streamed-zip-download-will-not-decompress-using-arch)

My debugging steps started as this:

1) Attempting to generate zip this using Amazon S3 stream

2) Tinkering with settings, removing compression

3) Isolating the problem to the simplest result

4) Adding output buffering & output flush to attempt to intercept any output.

My route is this:

`Route::get("/generate-zip", 'myController@generateZip');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately my problem was unrelated to the library.  I had (I think) accidentally saved a file inside /vendor that had some additional code in it.  Wiping the vendor folder and re-installing did the trick.